# AngularJS $routeProvider doesnt show template in ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So when i click the links in index.html the path in browser changes but it doesnt show the content of sivu1.html and sivu2.html

Here is my index.html

```
<html ng-app="appi">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="appi.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/sivu1">Sivu ykköne</a>
        <a href="/sivu2">Sivu kakkone</a>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the appi.js

```
var appi = angular.module("appi", ["ngRoute"]);

appi.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", 
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider.when
        ("/sivu1", {templateUrl: "templates/sivu1.html", controller: "sivu1controller"});

        $routeProvider.when
        ("/sivu2", {templateUrl: "templates/sivu2.html", controller: "sivu2controller"});

        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: "/home"});

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true, requireBase:false});
    }]);

appi.controller("sivu1controller",["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.viesti = "Tässä sivu ykkönen(1)";    
}]);

appi.controller("sivu2controller",["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.viesti = "Tässä sivu kakkonen(2)";    
}]);
```

sivu1.html and sivu2.html both have the same content

```
<h2>{{ viesti }}</h2>
```

### Folder structure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your href from

`<a href="/sivu1">Sivu ykköne</a>
\<a href="/sivu2">Sivu kakkone</a>`

To

```
<a href="#/sivu1">Sivu ykköne</a>
<a href="#/sivu2">Sivu kakkone</a>
```

It should be working now.

Comment: Still not working. When i click links it gives this in browser url field "http://localhost:8383/home#%2Fsivu1" and in netbeans' log "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (06:07:17:521 | error, network)
  at http://localhost:8383/favicon.ico"

Comment: check this link https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating    &   http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/routes.html